# Create dropdownlist in excel

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I created an excel sheet in java. I am using POI library for that. I don't know how to create a dropdownlist after clicking on that button. Also, I want to create hyperlinks for multiple cells in excel.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/), can you show us your code? so far

Comment: sorry, I don't have that code in my laptop. Please check this link: http://www.roseindia.net/answers/viewqa/Java-Beginners/14946-how-to-create-an-excel-file-using-java.html

Comment: In this way I created excel sheet. But I need to create dropdown list which will have sort A-Z Z-A options, checkboxes. Text filters with checkboxes, equals not equals etc

Comment: I checked on roseindia site for dropdown list. But I want that dropdown to be created after clicking on button which is at top right corner of cell.

Comment: @anil: Do you mean adding the "[Data filter](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/filter-data-in-a-range-or-table-HP010073941.aspx)" to the header columns?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Apache POI 3.5+`. It comes with lot of examples for advanced formatting that you can explore. For reference check out [POI Examples](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/examples.html) and [conditional format example](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/ss/examples/ConditionalFormats.java)